How to store access token in memory, variable or SavedStateHandle?
Problem with storing Access token in SavedStateHandle is that we are coupling presentation layer with the data layer, as what management of access token is task of data layer.
I haven't found much issue's with variable approach, but just thought of using SavedStateHandle as a possible approach.
